# Modify Java variable within JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, javascript, variables, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to modify the value of a Java variable from within Selenium    JavascriptExecutor?

I know it is possible to access Java variables inside JavascriptExecutor as `'"+myjavavar+"'` but how do we modify it?

If I use `'"+myjavavar+"'= somenewvalue;` it fails with error `"invalid assignment left-hand side"`.

Comment: You are probably confusing java and javascript here. You want to modify a *javascript variable* through `JavascriptExecutor`, right?

Comment: @alecxe No, I want to access and modify a java variable through JavascriptExecutor.

Comment: Could you add more details about the motivation behind this kind of requirement?

Comment: Basically what I am looking to achieve here is either (1) OR (2) of below. (1) As my JavascriptExecutor modifies some javascript variables, I need that values to be available within the java program. A kind of global javascript variable which can be used within both java and javascript.   (2) I have a java variable which has some initial value. I need to pass this value to JavascriptExecutor and within the JavascriptExecutor I will update this value on some conditions and then continue the java program with the new value. I don't want to use any cookies based global storage here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can both get and set javascript variables through `JavascriptExecutor`. To have a "global" variable during your test session available in every script you execute, keep it on the [global `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). Example:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// set the value (note how the arguments are passed into)
js.executeScript("window.myvar = arguments[0];", "Test");

// get the value (note the "return")
String myvar = (String) js.executeScript("return window.myvar;");
System.out.println(myvar);
```

Comment: Thanks...! Fair enough.